# Detect “Done” on iPhone for YouTube/Vimeo videos (exit fullscreen)

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I embedded an iframe video and I want to detect when the user has exited (tapped “done”) the fullscreen functionality on mobile Safari that takes place when you tap “play”. I tried the code below:

HTML

```
<iframe id="video-iframe" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/105953491?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;api=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("video-iframe").addEventListener("webkitendfullscreen", function(){
  alert("Hello World!");
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p3bLohfk/**

But it's not working (iOS 8.0.2). Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

On iOS 8, when the system video player takes over from the `UIWebView` on iOS, the main window of your application is hidden.  Listen for the `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` notifications on your view controller to detect when the user enters and exits the full screen player:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoDidExitFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoDidEnterFullScreen:)
                                                 name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];
```